# SSRS 2016 Parses Comments and Fails to Execute

Tags: reporting-services

After upgrading to SSRS 2016 from 2012, a lot of our reports were unable to execute for the simple fact that they had comments that included parameters in the query.

For example, just adding this to the SQL of a dataset:

```
-- This is just a comment with fake parameter :just_a_fake_parameter
```

Now when I try to run it in Visual Studio, I get the following error:

```
Invalid parameter binding: just_a_fake_parameter
```

Something more realistic:

```
-- 2017.04.27 EG: Updated Code
```

Throws:

```
Invalid parameter binding: Updated
```

I mean, why is a comment even read in the first place?